# Google Street View link (href) to Custom location

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view, hotlinking

I have having a hard time trying to decipher the Google Street View API and learn some Javascript along the way. I have this script I found online to reference custom panorama images. However my next goal is to link directly to a custom panoramic. So I have the basic script working like want it to, but in the final version I will have a column to the right of the street view with links pointing directly to certain locations so the end user will not have to navigate all around the map for one image.

Thanks for any help!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <title>Custom Street View panorama tiles</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
html, body, #map-canvas {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
  }
</style>
<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=jibberjabber0&callback=initialize">
</script>
<script>
var urlquery = window.location.search.substring(1);
//alert(query);


    var panorama;
    // The panorama that will be used as the entry point to the custom
    // panorama set.
    var entryPanoId = null;
    function initialize() {
      // The latlng of the entry point to the Google office on the road.
      var unionOffice = new google.maps.LatLng(38.4086774, -81.4638667);
      // Set up the map and enable the Street View control.
      var mapOptions = {
        center: unionOffice,
        zoom: 0
      };
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
          mapOptions);
      panorama = map.getStreetView();
      // Set up Street View and initially set it visible. Register the
      // custom panorama provider function.
      var panoOptions = {
        position: unionOffice,
        visible: true,
        panoProvider: getCustomPanorama
      };
      panorama.setOptions(panoOptions);
      // Create a StreetViewService object.
      var streetviewService = new google.maps.StreetViewService();
      // Compute the nearest panorama to the Google Sydney office
      // using the service and store that pano ID.
      var radius = 50;
      streetviewService.getPanoramaByLocation(unionOffice, radius,
          function(result, status) {
            console.log("1", arguments);
        if (status == google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK) {
          // We'll monitor the links_changed event to check if the current
          // pano is either a custom pano or our entry pano.
          google.maps.event.addListener(panorama, 'links_changed', function() {
              console.log("2", arguments);
              createCustomLinks(result.location.pano);
          });
          google.maps.event.addListener(panorama, 'position_changed', function() {
            console.log('panorama.getPosition()', panorama.getPosition());
          });
          google.maps.event.addListener(panorama, 'pov_changed', function() {
          });
        }
      });
    }
    function getCustomPanoramaTileUrl(pano, zoom, tileX, tileY) {
      // Return a pano image given the panoID.
      console.log('pana URL', arguments);
      if (pano === 'bayside'){
        return 'file:///J:/location/to/image/photo34.jpg';
      } else if(pano === 'desk') {
        return 'file:///J:/location/to/image/photo31.jpg';
      } else if(pano === 'meetingroom') {
        return 'file:///J:/location/to/image/photo32.jpg';
      }
    }

    //getCustomPanorama('bayside');
    //alert(urlquery);

    function getCustomPanorama(pano) {
      switch (pano) {
        case 'desk':
          return {
            location: {
              pano: 'desk',
              description: 'Developers Desk',
              latLng: new google.maps.LatLng(38.4086774, -81.4638667)
            },
            links: [],
            // The text for the copyright control.
            copyright: 'Imagery (c) 2010 Google',
            // The definition of the tiles for this panorama.
            tiles: {
              tileSize: new google.maps.Size(1047, 523),
              worldSize: new google.maps.Size(1047, 523),
              // tileSize: new google.maps.Size(1024, 512),
              // worldSize: new google.maps.Size(2048, 1024),
              // The heading at the origin of the panorama tile set.
              centerHeading: 105,
              getTileUrl: getCustomPanoramaTileUrl
            }
          };
          break;
        case 'bayside':
          return {
            location: {
              pano: 'bayside',
              description: '7 Seas Baysids',
              latLng: new google.maps.LatLng(43.649179, -79.391393)
            },
            links: [],
            // The text for the copyright control.
            copyright: 'Imagery (c) 2010 Google',
            // The definition of the tiles for this panorama.
            tiles: {
              tileSize: new google.maps.Size(1047, 523),
              worldSize: new google.maps.Size(1047, 523),
              // tileSize: new google.maps.Size(1024, 512),
              // worldSize: new google.maps.Size(2048, 1024),
              // The heading at the origin of the panorama tile set.
              centerHeading: 105,
              getTileUrl: getCustomPanoramaTileUrl
            }
          };
          break;
        case 'meetingroom':
          return {
            location: {
              pano: 'meetingroom',
              description: 'Meeting Room',
              latLng: new google.maps.LatLng(43.649141, -79.391396)
            },
            links: [],
            // The text for the copyright control.
            copyright: 'Imagery (c) 2010 Google',
            // The definition of the tiles for this panorama.
            tiles: {
              tileSize: new google.maps.Size(3000, 1500),
              worldSize: new google.maps.Size(3000, 1500),
              // tileSize: new google.maps.Size(1024, 512),
              // worldSize: new google.maps.Size(2048, 1024),
              // The heading at the origin of the panorama tile set.
              centerHeading: 105,
              getTileUrl: getCustomPanoramaTileUrl
            }
          };
          break;
        default:
          return null;
      }
    }


    function createCustomLinks(entryPanoId) {
      var links = panorama.getLinks();
      var panoId = panorama.getPano();
      switch (panoId) {
        case entryPanoId:
          // Adding a link in the view from the entrance of the building to
          // reception.
          links.push({
            heading: 15,
            description: 'UNION',
            pano: 'bayside'
          });
          break;
        case 'desk':
          // Adding a link in the view from the entrance of the office
          // with an arrow pointing at 100 degrees, with a text of 'Exit'
          // and loading the street entrance of the building pano on click.
          links.push({
            heading: 195,
            description: 'UNION',
            pano: 'bayside'
          });
          links.push({
            heading: 260,
            description: 'Meeting Room',
            pano: 'meetingroom'
          });
          break;
          case 'bayside':
          // Adding a link in the view from the entrance of the office
          // with an arrow pointing at 100 degrees, with a text of 'Exit'
          // and loading the street entrance of the building pano on click.
          links.push({
            heading: 180,
            description: 'Exit',
            pano: entryPanoId
          });
          links.push({
            heading: 360,
            description: 'Developers Desk',
            pano: 'desk'
          });
          break;
          case 'meetingroom':
          // Adding a link in the view from the entrance of the office
          // with an arrow pointing at 100 degrees, with a text of 'Exit'
          // and loading the street entrance of the building pano on click.
          links.push({
            heading: 30,
            description: 'Developers Desk',
            pano: 'desk'
          });
          break;
        default:
          return;
      }
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just reduce the width of the #map-canvas div, add another div, give your new div width, and float it to the right, and you should have your column to the right to populate with whatever data you want.

Your question however is not clear enough so this might not be what you are looking for.

Just an example:

```
<style>
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
  }
#map-canvas {
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
}
#col-right {
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
}
</style>
```

and further in your code...

```
<body>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<div id="col-right">Populate with data</div>
</body>
```